# How to get file id and disconnect openfile?

Tags: windows, powershell, 7zip

I am using PS script to extract files on specified location. Unfortunately i need to overwrite them and sometimes they are in use.
I am considering using "openfiles /disconnect" on few files before unzipping, to get sure, that files overwrites well.

How cant i get specified file id, and disconnect all sessions for overwriting?

Thank you

```powershell
if ($name.Contains('something'))
 {
## Openfiles?
 Get-ChildItem \\server\load\$name | 
 % {
 & "C:\test\7z.exe" "x" -aoa -y $_.fullname "-o\\server\output"
   }
  }
else
{
"$name unknown"
}
```

Comment: files to disconnect is in output folder like "\\server\output\file1.db" As i understand if I overwrite it fileID will change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you disconnect an SMB session it will be re-established almost immediately by the client you disconnected. One clean way of achieving your requirements is to:

1. unshare the *\\server\output* on the server and share it
2. share it with *Full Permissions* only to yourself, ie. the user which does the unzipping
3. run your unzipping code
4. reverse step 1.

Comment: Sorry unshare the whole folder is not a very good solution. Maybe temporary change of permissions is needed. I don't know what is best practice for this action. Thank you though.

Comment: Would it be practical to keep those files flagged as ReadOnly, to prevent anyone from getting a write lock? You should be able to unzip to a temp location, then overwrite them with Copy-Item -Force.

Comment: If the files are opened via SMB share the _only_ option is to unshare(or unzip when no files are opened). An already opened  file  will have a write handle which needs to be dropeed; disconnecting a session will be re-established nearly immediately. @WhiteHorse, if you script doesn't take long the unshare/unzip/share will be nigh invisible to your users.